# South causing Django 1.5 to crash on production

Tags: django, django-south

I've been fighting with South for a week now and making no progress :(

I have my website working perfectly without South, but as soon as I add South to the site, I get an error log full of weird errors that don't tell me anything (I'm developing on the actual hosting account, because nobody but me has been given the URL yet anyway). However, with South enabled, the development server works just fine, just not Apache.

Anything you can suggest would be much appreciated :)

For a bit of background, I have implemented a custom User class for authentication. I am using a Hostgator shared hosting account, which I think uses Apache and mod_fcgi. Here is the error log from Apache (the line 7 it refers to in my root urlconf is the line "admin.autodiscover()"):

```
[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File
"/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line
35, in import_module

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File 
"/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation
/trans_real.py", line 154, in _fetch

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File 
"/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 172, in translation

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 258, in do_translate

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 276, in ugettext

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 71, in ugettext

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 130, in __text_cast

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 99, in force_text

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 35, in format

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 216, in r

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 35, in format

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 312, in format

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 715, in date

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 606, in resolve

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 84, in render

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 298, in get_traceback_html

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 69, in technical_500_response

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in handle_uncaught_exception

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response

[Tue Jul 23 00:27:40 2013] [warn] [client 137.186.44.205] mod_fcgid: stderr:   File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 94, in load_app
File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 72, in _populate
File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 134, in get_apps
File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/validation.py", line 22, in validate
File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 98, in register
File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py", line 178, in <module>
File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 29, in autodiscover
File "/home1/outreach/outreach/outreach/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 347, in url_patterns
File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 319, in resolve
File "/home1/outreach/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 103, in get_response`
```

Comment: The error seems to be with importing your admin module, nothing about south there. Try calling `admin.autodiscover()` from django shell and see what it says.

Comment: It doesn't produce any errors. The site also works with the development server.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to South at all, just wrong server configuration. Have you taken special precautions to allow FastCGI to work? Normally Django is configured using some sort of wsgi interface. For example see [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1307/).

Comment: Everything works perfectly whenever South is not enabled. There is an index.fcgi file and a .htaccess file that handle the fastCGI stuff. I'm afraid all that is way above my head.

Comment: What do you mean by enabling south? Did you install it properly on the server? Syncdb and all?

Comment: Yes, when I enable South, I flush the entire DB with manage.py reset_db (from django-extensions), then use syncdb with South added to INSTALLED_APPS.